# Отстает прорисовка изображения в picturebox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

При изменении значения в numericupdown изображение отстает на 1 перерисовку.
Например при изменении значения с 50 на 51 на picturebox'е будет прорисовано изображение которое должно было быть прорисовано при значении 50

```
public void NumericUpDownValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Draw(g1);
}
private void Draw(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)numericUpDown1.Value, 40, 200, 100));
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нужно больше кода. Откуда берется изображение?

Comment: У вас сначала рисуется картинка, а потом считывается значение из апдауна. Поэтому и отстает. Должно быть наоборот.